# Insert image below invoice PDF in Magento

Tags: image, magento, pdf

I am trying to put a image below the invoice in the PDF file. I have tried a few extension but they aren't working properly on my site.

[image]

Any sort of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest posting this on the Magento site instead: http://magento.stackexchange.com/  If you do, be sure to include a little more information: which extensions have you tried?  What is and isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to modify your invoice pdf design. [Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/orders/editing_an_invoice_pdf) is the link that shows how to move your image to the desired location in your pdf. Have a look at this.

Hope this will work for you.